# How can I select a single color within an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, selections, paint.net

How would one pick or select all of a single color within Photoshop, Paint.NET, or The Gimp?

The objective is to edit everything with that color afterwards, such as by brushing over it with another color. So if I were to select a certain red hue of an apple, then brushed it over with pink, only all of the parts of the apple with that red color would then be pink. I could use the magic wand tool, but don't know if there's something that can scan the image for every pixel with that color.

Comment: This somewhat depends upon the image. Can you add a sample image to your question?

Comment: I don't have one in mind. I'll think of something and add it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe i do not understand entirely, but can you not - in photoshop - select the colour then choose "similar". Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I don't have PS at the moment, but that would've helped out a lot in graphic arts.

Comment: I am confused; did @Gramps answer your question correctly?

Comment: I think a comment here and Alan Gilbertson have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a vague question so I'm just going to answer it with what I've used before.

### [In Photoshop](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/choosing-colors.html#choose_colors_with_the_eyedropper_tool):

You would use the eyedropper tool [image] shortcut <kbd>I</kbd>.

### [In Gimp](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-color-picker.html):

You would use the color picker tool [image] shortcut <kbd>O</kbd>.

### In Paint:

Also called the Color Picker Tool [image]

### Imagemagick command line:

`convert <image> -unique-colors -depth 8 txt:- > output.txt`

### [Imagemagick PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagepixelcolor.php):

`ImagickPixel Imagick::getImagePixelColor ( int $x , int $y )`

### jQuery/JavaScript:

- [Color Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/): The documentation for it is bad but there project is solid.
- [palette](https://github.com/visionmedia/palette): Very simple tool.

### More PHP:

- [ColorPalette](https://github.com/Projekod/ColorPalette): Returns an array of all the colors in hex .
- [Color Thief in PHP](https://github.com/ksubileau/color-thief-php): Same as the jQuery one but just written in PHP.

Answer (score 7):

### Gimp - Select by Color

In Gimp we have the *Select by Color* tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) to allow a selection based on image color.

[image]

#### Select by Color - Threshold `0`

By selecting a color difference threshold of `0` we will select only parts of the image with **exactly** the same color value (below shown for white):

[image]
<sup>Image Source: [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:InflatableBalloons.jpg)</sup>

#### Select by Color - Threshold `50`

To select similar colors we need to increase the threshold, in the example below light green with a threshold of `50` was selected. While keeping the left mouse button pressed on selecting we can adjust this threshold visually while dragging the mouse pointer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To select a color, the Photoshop approach is to use `Select > Color Range...`. To positively select just a single color, either turn off `Localized Color Groups` or set the `Range` slider to 100%.

If your color is very well-defined and you don't need an anti-aliased or soft-edged selection, you can use the Magic Wand tool. Set the sample size (which you have to do via the Eyedropper tool in earlier versions of Photoshop) to 3x3 or 5x5 average, and click on the color you're trying to select.

If all you want to do is sample the color, then the alternatives Gramps outlined are correct, although I would again suggest you set the sample size to something larger than a single pixel if the image is jpeg compressed.

Answer (score 1):

### Photoshop

(the principle should be the same in other programmes)

I might have misunderstood, but you are trying to select *all* fields of one specific colour in an image?

In photoshop:

use the `magic wand tool`:

[image]

Select an area with the colour you want, fiddle with the `tolerance` depending on your image:

[image]

Right-click on the area you have selected, and choose `similar` from the menu:

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I want it to select every single color or one hue of the image and edit from there.

Comment: If the above answer does not do the job for you, i do not understand what you want. It would be good if you could edit your question to elaborate a little.