# How can I do a global fuzzy select in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

How can I make the fuzzy select global in GIMP, so that it selects all of a certain color and not just contiguous regions?

For example, if I drew multiple red squiggles, how could I easily select them all?

Comment: see here for "select by color": http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31022/how-can-i-select-a-single-color-within-an-image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shift + O or Tools -> Selection Tools -> By Color Select

For more information please view the [Gimp Documentation, section 2.6 select by color](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html).

Answer (score 0):

GIMP has a tool that selects by color. The icon looks like three squares stacked that are blue,red and green and to the left is a yellow pentagon pointing in between blue and red.